# how to calculate partial derivative?

Tags: integration, derivatives

how do I find 
$\frac{\partial q}{\partial k}$ of
 $q(k,l,m) = k\,p(k,l) + m^2$  ?

I have tried

$\frac{\partial q}{\partial k}= p(k,l) \times\begin{bmatrix}\frac{dk}{dm}+\frac{dl}{dm}\end{bmatrix} + p(k,l)\\
\frac{\partial q}{\partial l} = k\,p'_l(k,l)\,
\\\frac{\partial q}{\partial m} = 2m$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here it is:
$$
\frac{\partial q}{\partial k}= 1p(k,l) + k \times\frac{\partial p}{\partial k}\\
\frac{\partial q}{\partial l}= k \times\frac{\partial p}{\partial l}\
\
\\\frac{\partial q}{\partial m} = \frac{\partial k}{\partial m}p(k,l) + k \times\frac{\partial p}{\partial m}+2m=\frac{\partial k}{\partial m}p(k,l)+k \times\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial p}{\partial k}\frac{\partial k}{\partial m}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial l}\frac{\partial l}{\partial m}\end{bmatrix} + 2m\
$$

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missing something here:

-ignore the $m^{2}$ because it is constant w.r.t. k

-Use the product rule on $kp(k,l)$ :

$\partial_{k}$$kp(k,l)$=$p(k,l)+k\partial_{k}p(k,l)$

I am not sure whether this is what you were asking though....